# *.dmp file import in Oracle

Tags: oracle, import, schema

I need to import data from *.dmp file say mydump.dmp. 
What I'm doing is:

```
imp myuser/mypass file=mydump.dmp log=mylog.log
```

And I'm getting:

```
only a DBA can import a file exported by another DBA
```

I know the DBA credentianls to db but I want to import dump into 'myuser' schema.
So how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imp system/xxx file=mydump.dmp log=mylog.log touser=`destination_schema`

You have to import as system, since it was exported as system

Regards

Comment: Just a couple of comments - the user doesn't have to be SYSTEM, but can be any schema with SYSDBA privs.  Also, you should probably specify the original owner of the objects that you exported with the "FROMUSER=" clause.